# Getting error "ERROR: id not found" when running docker-compose on Alpine Linux v3.17

Tags: docker-compose, runtime-error, alpine-linux

When running any "docker-compose up -d" command on Alpine Linux v3.17 e.g. when using

```
git clone https://github.com/mwoodpatrick/docker-compose-test
cd docker-compose-test
docker-compose up -d
```

I am getting the error:

```
ERROR: id not found
```

Does anyone have any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I don't have such a behaviour. Could you share the full logs?

Comment: This test is using standard images so it's not building anything and if I run

docker-compose  --log-level DEBUG up -d --force-recreate
Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
ERROR: id not found

I'm not seeing any issues in the kernel log, how can I get more details?